# Battery icon missing from task bar

Tags: windows-vista, taskbar, icons, battery

I used to have an icon on the Windows Vista taskbar showing the battery amount remaining (laptop). It has mysteriously vanished.

How can I get it back?

I followed the Windows [FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Battery-meter-frequently-asked-questions) (see How can I hide the battery icon in the notification area? - hoping to reverse the instructions) but the Power checkbox on the Notification Area tab was greyed out and could not be checked or unchecked (it is currently unchecked).

Comment: It appears the answer submitted by someone else has been deleted. Anyone know why?

Comment: They can delete it themselves if they didn't like the answer, repeated your answer, were incorrect etc.

Comment: @Joe Taylor - thanks Joe. I was wondering if there was a *specific* reason on this occasion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution: [Fix Network, Clock, Volume and Power (Battery) System Icons Missing with Disabled or Grayed Out Check Box Options](http://www.mydigitallife.info/fix-network-clock-volume-and-power-battery-system-icons-missing-with-disabled-or-grayed-out-check-box-options/).

In my case I had to delete two settings in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify` (see the end of the article).

Comment: The link is broken. Can you share a working link or write full answer. (4 years passed after the answer ;)

Comment: @Jet - Link update.  I can confirm that solution works on Desktops.  I just did a search for the article title I had no problem finding it.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for update, but couldn't get it working on my Win7 desktop computer. I changed Group Policy, deleted that reg keys, but no effect (even after restarting).