# Windows 8 power icon

Tags: windows-8, power, battery

The power icon in my taskbar is disabled. When I try to customize by triggering the system icons on or off, that particular portion of power is also *grayed* so that I can't use it anymore...

Then, I tried all methods in the answer to this question already here: [Battery icon missing from task bar](https://superuser.com/questions/219480/battery-icon-missing-from-task-bar)

Still, I can't get my power icon back. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: A screen shot will be more helpful about the turn on/off.

Comment: This sounds like a driver problem.  Have you updated all your drivers?  Yes, the battery information is handled by a driver.

Comment: thanks@Ramhound the problem got solved after installing the driver.

Comment: @Ramhound , can you make your comment as an answer so that i can accept it? :)

Comment: And what if it's Desktop PC? @Ramhound What drivers should I install?

Comment: @Jet - None.  You just have to enable the icon.  You can still create power profiles on a desktop.  Its just the taskbar icon is disable by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the 2nd comment above, installing the power management driver has removed the problem.

Thing is my lan, wifi and all other things were automatically working after win 8 installation , so i never bothered to install any driver. And i didn't know that this battery info is handled by a driver.

Installating the concerned driver, solved the issue. So the mods can please close this q.

Comment: You don't need to close this question. Just request to @Ramhound to make his comment as an answer and you should accept it.

Comment: If he don't post it as an answer then you can accept your own answer for help to future readers. :)