# Battery Icon randomy disappears from windows 10

Tags: windows-10, battery, taskbar, icons

Windows 10 64bit.

Sometimes after resuming my computer from sleep, the battery icon disappears from the taskbar. Restarting windows explorer does not work. The option in the settings app shows the switch for the battery icon as grayed out.

edit: I know about the registry tweak, but that fixes it temporarily, and is for if the icon disappears. When I restart the computer, it fixes itself. If the registry tweak has already been applied, but it still happens. Therefore I can conclude that this is a different issue than the older post which talks about vista.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Battery icon missing from task bar](http://superuser.com/questions/219480/battery-icon-missing-from-task-bar)

Comment: @7h3w1z4rd Did you try the suggested solution before deciding it doesn't apply?  In many (most) cases, Windows' registry hasn't changed very much since Vista, so you *can* easily compare the two.

Comment: @7h3w1z4rd - When the instructions to bring the notification icon back are identical.  I can indeed flag a question with an answer as a possible duplicate.  If you don't agree, don't vote to close, but my opionion won't be changed.  How do I know they are identical? *I used a very similar registry tweak to solve a problem I had a few months ago.*

Comment: @Ramhound Registry tweak is only a temporary fix, I am updating the question accordingly.

Comment: Did this system come with Windows 10?  If it did not come with Windows 10 installed, what version of Windows, did it come installed with?  Have you installed the required drivers which specifically indicate Windows 10 support?

Comment: @Ramhound Updated from windows 8.1. All drivers should be up to date, and I have used the refresh/reset feature once, so it is probably not residual from win 8.1

Comment: The Refresh/Reset feature in Windows 8.1 reinstalls Windows I doubt your problems are caused by using it.